# Variable in jQuery selector for input element's value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

So quick summary: I'm making a single page quiz in HTML. It has 4 radio buttons with 4 labels. There is a Next button that replaces the question and answers in my quiz when clicked. I also record the user's answers whenever they click the Next button. There's a bit more, but that's the main gist of my code.

Here's some sample code:

```
<form name="form1">
  <label for="ans0">
    <input type="radio" name="answer" id="ans0" value=0>
  </label>
  <input type="button" id="next" value="Next">
  <input type="button" id="back" value="Back">
</form>
```

```js
function nextClick() {
  //jots down answers
  answerSheet[currentQuestion] = $("#form1 input[name='answer']:checked").val();
  ...
  currentQuestion++;
  populateQA();
  ...
}

function populateQA() {
  //code to replace question and answers from an array
}

function backClick() {
  currentQuestion--;                 // Navigates to the last question
  var prevAns = answerSheet[currentQuestion];
  alert(prevAns);                    // my test
  $("#form1 input[value=" + prevAns + "]").attr("checked", true);
  populateQA();
}

var currentQuestion = 0;
var answerSheet = [];

$("#next").on("click", nextClick);
$("#back").on("click", backClick);
```

The code in question is this, inside the backClick() function:

```
$("#form1 input[value=" + prevAns + "]").attr("checked", true);
```

I tried debugging it in Chrome, and alert(prevAns) returns the correct value every time. And if I manually execute the above line but with an actual number instead of the variable, e.g. value='0', in the console the radio button of that number gets checked as planned. So I don't know what's wrong, the syntax looks right? Why won't it work?

Comment: try `prop()` instead of `attr()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `prop` instead of `attr` for input[type=radio]:

```
$("#selector").prop("checked", true)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was stumped since manually entering the line with attr still worked

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#form1 input[value='" + prevAns + "']").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @PatrickHund, Thanks for your valuable input, i'll add explanation in the post while answering from next time. :)